# Is there a Christian counterpart to practical kabbalah?

Tags: judaism, mysticism

Wikipedia says [practical kabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_Kabbalah) is permitted white magic within Judaism. I know of the Old Testament injunctions against various types of sorcery, divination, etc., so this is quite a surprise to me. Is there a Christian practice that corresponds to this one?

Comment: Does transubstantiation count? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Esoteric Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_Christianity) historically taught "theurgy" or divine magic.  Modern practitioners incorporate "Eastern" or "New Age" beliefs such as like reincarnation, inner energy, magic, astrology, etc.  I would say it shares a lot in common with Kabbalah.

Comment: Although I do not know any practitioners of esoteric christianity or practical kabbalah, it seems like esoteric christianity would be pretty widely rejected while practical kabbalah was accepted. I may certainly be incorrect so I'll accept this in a few days if no one else chimes in.

Comment: @sirdank While I agree few traditional Christians would accept Esoteric beliefs as valid Christianity, I don't think very may Orthodox Jews would accept Kabbalah as having any validity within Judaism either.  If the question is does any mainstream Christian group accept magic, the answer is "no";  if the question is does any vaguely Christian group accept it, then I'd say the Esoterics qualify.